# Increase Checkbox Size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I increase the width and height of a checkbox? I tried to increase the width and height inside  **.list-group input[type="checkbox"] + label:before** based on other examples but the size of the box is not changing.

```html
<ul class="list-group ml-3 mr-3 mt-1 " style="background-color:pink; height:auto">

    <li class="list-group-item d-flex p-0 border-0 ">
        <input style="background-color:yellow" class="" type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" />
        <label style="font-size: 15px;"class="list-group-item w-100 p-0 border-0" for="CheckBox1">Caption asdsad asdasd </label>
    </li>

</ul>
```

```css
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.list-group input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}       

.list-group input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    content: "\2714";
    border: 0.1em solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: transparent;
    width: 10px; // this is not working
    height: 20px; // this is not working
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` into `.list-group input[type="checkbox"] + label:before`.